# Need to remove trailing zeros from the date column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, dbi

I want to remove trailing zeros from result set after query execution.

My Code:

```
driver <- JDBC(driver)
url <- "jdbc url"
conn<- dbConnect(driver,url)
copyofsourceData<- dbGetQuery(conn,query)
```

Date format in Result set: 2015-03-09 10:11:15.000000
I want to remove zeros including decimal

Comment: Can you share `dput(head(copyofsourceData))` ?

Comment: structure(list(order_item_id = 389, comp_id = 2366, maint_tms = "2018-05-14 15:48:36.000000", 
    create_dat = "2018-05-14 15:48:36.000000", comp_nam = "Mediterranean Hummus, Half Size", 
    comp_des = "GREAT NORTHERN BEANS, RED BELL PEPPERS, WATER, TAHINI PASTE (SESAME SEEDS), EXTRA VIRGIN OLIVE OIL, NATURAL FLAVOUR, GARLIC, CONCENTRATED LIME JUICE, \n\nSALT, SUGAR, DEHYDRATED GARLIC, CITRIC ACID, DEHYDRATED ONION, SPICES, SESAME SEEDS, RED CHILI PEPPER.\nCONTAINS: SESAME SEEDS\n"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0):

The columns are of class "character", you can change it to `POSIXct`.

```
cols <- c("maint_tms", "create_dat")
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], as.POSIXct, tz = "UTC")
```

Or using `dplyr` + `lubridate`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_at(cols, lubridate::ymd_hms)
```